# Angular Build html saying StaticInjectorError[e -> e]

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am having problem in angular build.

Ng server is working fine.
But when I build my app it builds file and when I open the html it say following error.

```
main.aad9c1dbd7274baabb39.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[e -> e]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[e -> e]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for e!
Error: StaticInjectorError[e -> e]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[e -> e]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for e!
    at e.get (main.aad9c1dbd7274baabb39.js:1)
    at main.aad9c1dbd7274baabb39.js:1
    at e (main.aad9c1dbd7274baabb39.js:1)
    at e.get (main.aad9c1dbd7274baabb39.js:1)
    at main.aad9c1dbd7274baabb39.js:1
    at e (main.aad9c1dbd7274baabb39.js:1)
    at e.get (main.aad9c1dbd7274baabb39.js:1)
    at Bg (main.aad9c1dbd7274baabb39.js:1)
    at main.aad9c1dbd7274baabb39.js:1
    at Rg (main.aad9c1dbd7274baabb39.js:1)
    at O (polyfills.20ab2d163684112c2aba.js:1)
    at O (polyfills.20ab2d163684112c2aba.js:1)
    at polyfills.20ab2d163684112c2aba.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.20ab2d163684112c2aba.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.aad9c1dbd7274baabb39.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.20ab2d163684112c2aba.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.20ab2d163684112c2aba.js:1)
    at v (polyfills.20ab2d163684112c2aba.js:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please import `HttpClientModule`

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    HttpClientModule
]})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is related to Angular CLI version issue also. Which angular version you are using. As far as I know, this issue was, particularly in Angular 4 version which angular team had fixed.

Second please check if your local CLI and global CLI version are mismatched. If yes, try to keep it on the same versions. Please use below commands to check if it resolves the issue:

```
try this

npm outdated
npm update
OR
`
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm uninstall -g angular/cli

npm cache clean

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
`
```

You can also follow this thread to resolve your issue: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7210

Let me know if it helps.